# Daily Add/Del Git Log Analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, git

I just finished writing this Python script to calculate daily additions and subtractions from my git log to use in making pretty graphs. This is a rewrite of something I wrote previously in Perl. I have made an attempt to clean it up, but I feel that some of my list comprehensions are messy to say the least, and I'm abusing certain Python features.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# get-pmstats.py
# Henry J Schmale
# November 25, 2017
# 
# Calculates the additions and deletions per day within a git repository
# by parsing out the git log. It opens the log itself.
# Produces output as a CSV
#
# This segments out certain file wildcards

import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
from fnmatch import fnmatch

def chomp_int(val):
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

def make_fn_matcher(args):
    return lambda x: fnmatch(''.join(map(str, args[2:])), x)

def print_results(changes_by_date):
    print('date,ins,del')
    for key,vals in changes_by_date.items():
        print(','.join(map(str, [key, vals[0], vals[1]])))

EXCLUDED_WILDCARDS = ['*.eps', '*.CSV', '*jquery*']

changes_by_date = {}
git_log = subprocess.Popen(
    'git log --numstat --pretty="%at"',
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True)

date = None
day_changes = [0, 0]
for line in git_log.stdout:
    args = line.decode('utf8').rstrip().split()
    if len(args) == 1:
        old_date = date
        date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(args[0]))
        if day_changes != [0, 0] and date.date() != old_date.date():
            changes_by_date[str(date.date())] = day_changes
            day_changes = [0, 0]
    elif len(args) >= 3:
        # Don't count changesets for excluded file types
        if True in map(make_fn_matcher(args), EXCLUDED_WILDCARDS):
            continue
        day_changes = [sum(x) for x in zip(day_changes, map(chomp_int, args[0:2]))]
print_results(changes_by_date)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would apply the following improvements:

- use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to count down the number of added and deleted lines separately. This would help to improve the counting logic and avoid having to check for the old date at all
- use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check for the excluded wildcards
- *unpack* `args` into added, deleted lines and a filename
- switch to [`gitpython`](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) from `subprocess`

The new version of the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
from fnmatch import fnmatch

import git


EXCLUDED_WILDCARDS = ['*.eps', '*.CSV', '*jquery*']


def chomp_int(val):
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        return 0


repo = git.Repo(".")
git_log = repo.git.log(numstat=True, pretty="%at").encode("utf-8")

added, deleted = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(int)

for line in git_log.splitlines():
    args = line.decode('utf8').rstrip().split()

    if len(args) == 1:
        date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(args[0])).date()
    elif len(args) >= 3:
        added_lines, deleted_lines, filename = args

        # Don't count changesets for excluded file types
        if any(fnmatch(filename, wildcard) for wildcard in EXCLUDED_WILDCARDS):
            continue

        added[date] += chomp_int(added_lines)
        deleted[date] += chomp_int(deleted_lines)

for date, added_lines in added.items():
    print(date, added_lines, deleted[date])
```

Comment: Looks like you have potential for an error on you `elif`'s tuple unpacking

Comment: @Peilonrayz good point. I was thinking to add a `*_` there, but experimented with a couple repositories I had cloned and could not find a case where `args` has more than 3 - not sure if it is possible to get with the `git log --numstat --pretty="%at"`. But, yes, it should be `== 3` if I am assuming that. Thanks!